# How were .NET framework reference source files autogenerated?

Tags: .net, reference-source

Apparently a lot of the source files in the reference source for the .NET Framework were autogenerated code, by some means. On some source files a header comment says:

```
// This file was generated, please do not edit it directly.
//
// Please see http://wiki/default.aspx/Microsoft.Projects.Avalon/MilCodeGen.html for more information.
```

([Example](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Generated/Rect.cs))

But the URL in the comment doesn't work - the hostname doesn't make any sense for an Internet site. Maybe this was originally internal to Microsoft or some other organization?

I don't necessarily need to access this exact page (which obviously may be internal / private somewhere) but I am interested if anyone knowledgeable can at least explain the gist of what it would have said.

FYI when I've searched for this URL or substrings of it, the only hits I find are just to pages in the reference source itself which contain the same comment.

Thanks

Comment: You can find some references to MilCodeGen in the [Wpf Github source](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/tree/master/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/WpfGfx/codegen/mcg), under `src/WpfGfx/codegen/mcg`. I've just found that so can't craft a more specific answer at present.

Comment: Source code was written with the assumption that only Microsoft employees would ever see it.  Avalon was the internal project name for WPF, the URL refers to an intranet site.

Comment: @HansPassant appreciate the insight. From what you know, is it likely there is anything in that internal document which would be pertinent when studying the ref sources?  For instance I noticed that Rect was a partial struct: some generated code + some apparently handwritten. I was not sure what the basis of that would be. (example)

Comment: Probably.  But it is academic, you can't get to it.  Perhaps better, this was written about 17 years ago and the odds that anybody kept it up to date are low.